# Passing variable from php to javascript for use as an ID

Tags: javascript, php

I am attempting to build a small application where our editors can choose to hide some elements, in this case, Job Names, from a page when it is printed.

However, I cannot seem to get the addclass to work properly. It either does nothing or it adds the class to every checkbox.

To give my checkboxes a unique id, I am using the job name as the ID in php. These come from a database.
Input:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='".$row['name']"'/><div class='tohide ".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var src = <?php echo json_encode($row['name']); ?>;
  $('input#src').change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
      $('.tohide').addClass('bold noprint');
    }else{
      $('.tohide').removeClass('bold noprint');
    }
  })
```

I have noticed that `<?php echo json_encode($row['name']); ?>` and `<?php echo $row['name']; ?>` do not give any results. I am using the same `$row['name']` inside the php to generate proper ID'd for the checkboxes.

Client Side code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var src = "";
      $('input#'+ src).change(function(){
        if(this.checked){
          $('.tohide').addClass('bold noprint');
        }
        else {
          $('.tohide').removeClass('bold noprint');
        }
      })
    </script>
```

When using `json_encode` I do get a value of null

Comment: And what is the resulting client-side code this generates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem why all checboxes change is this:

```
$('.tohide').removeClass('bold noprint');
```

All your checkboxes match the expression ".tohide".

You'll want to do `$('.tohide.'+this.id).removeClass('bold noprint')` instead.

Disclaimer: not tested since you did not provide valid HTML and this is a HTML / JS question. The PHP part is irrelevant.

Comment: This will hide the checkbox when checked, but not the value next to it.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right. My bad. You'll want to use the .siblings() method probably.

Comment: That did it. Add it to the answer so I can select it please.

Comment: I changed the answer to use a reference with the ID. But if you report exactly what you did, I can update the answer so it reflects the actual solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a string:

```
'input#src'
```

It's not going to interpolate a variable name within the string, it's just a literal string.  To use the `src` variable, concatenate it:

```
'input#' + src
```

---

I also *suspect* that this may be incorrect:

```
var src = <?php echo json_encode($row['name']); ?>;
```

Though you *really should* look at the actual client-side code to confirm.  But if the value is simply a string then I doubt you need `json_encode`.  But you would definitely need *quotes* around a string:

```
var src = '<?php echo $row['name']; ?>';
```

Comment: Thank you @David. However, I am getting an Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input#

Comment: @Concrete-Cowboy: Sounds like you made an error somewhere then.  Likely a string quoting mistake.  What's the code which produces that error?

Comment: Full code of javascript:
    var src = '<?php echo $row['name']; ?>';
          $('input#'+ src).change(function(){
            if(this.checked){
              $('.tohide').addClass('bold noprint');
            }
            else {
              $('.tohide').removeClass('bold noprint');
            }
          })

Comment: When I do a console.log(src) I do not get any results

Comment: @Concrete-Cowboy: Please put code in the question for readability, and include the *client-side* code that's generating the error, not the *server-side* code that generates the client-side code.